# Can I re-use a "plug-and-play" CPU liquid cooling setup?

Tags: cpu, cooling, desktop-computer

I'm wondering if I want to upgrade my CPU sometime down the road, would I have to scrap my existing liquid cooling? Note: it is not a custom liquid cooling setup, it is a pre-built plug and play liquid cooling.

The exact model is: Cooler Master Nepton 240M

If it is possible to retain it, what do I have to do to make sure it holds up until I install it to my next CPU?

Specifically I'm wondering if there are any complicated steps to be considered with regards to:

- thermal paste removal
- preventing liquid from leaking
- long term storage while uninstalled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just changing the CPU you would just need to apply new paste. If you change other components like CPU and motherboard you would need to check whenever it's supported to mount your cooler on that kind of board with the specific kind of CPU.

As for long term storage ... it's unlikely that you will use it again if you need to put it away for an extended time so you're probably better of trying to sell it. But you could store it of course. Preferably you'd use the original packaging otherwise make sure you don't bend the tubes too much and that there is no unnecessary strain on any of the parts.

Comment: That clears things up a good bit, thank you. I do know that 7th gen CPUs need a motherboard that supports that chipset. But when you say check compatibility of the cooler and the motherboard, you mean just make sure the connection / mounting screws and what not are there right? Or would putting a Nepton 240 on a 7th gen supporting motherboard be more complicated than that?

Comment: Check the manual of the cooler for the supported sockets and yes it would come down to having all the right brackets and screws in order to actually mount it. Sometimes the distances of the screw holes change. If you check the current information page for that cooler model it supports: `Intel LGA 2066 / 2011-3 / 2011 / 1366 / 1150 / 1151 /1155 / 1156 / 775
AMD Socket FM2+ / FM2 / FM1 / AM3+ / AM3 / AM2` in its current iteration. It should work for most current Intels but e.g. no Ryzen (AM4).